# How to define a macro that can use symbols from the same crate

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to create my own macro which will behave almost like `json!` macro but instead of getting a `serde::Value` I want to get my own struct.

I am half-way successful with following code, but the macro can't be used outside this file as it shows errors like "cannot find type `Person` in this scope" or "cannot find macro `json` in this scope".

```rust
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::json;

mod utils;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! person_parse {
    ($json:tt) => {
        serde_json::from_value::<Person>(json!($json)).unwrap()
    };
}

fn main() {
    let john: Person = person_parse!({
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 43,
    });

    println!("{:?}", john);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros expand into normal code so if a name is not imported it will not be found in the file that uses it. You could import the Person struct and json! macro in the other file, but that is a bit unergonomic. You can however use fully qualified names in the macro and in that way you won't need to add imports.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! person_parse {
    ($json:tt) => {
        serde_json::from_value::<$crate::Person>(serde_json::json!($json)).unwrap()
    };
}
```

Here we are using a $crate metavariable that refers to the current crate and we added `serde_json::` before the `json!` macro use.

You can learn more about macros here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html

Comment: An alternative would be to just add the `use $crate::Person;` within the macro. You get to use short names and the user doesn't need to have the symbol in scope.